# Code for a multiple quadratic (or polynomial) least squares (surface fit)?

Tags: image-processing, curve-fitting, least-squares

for a machine vision project I am trying to search image data for quadratic surfaces (f(x,y) = Ax^2+Bx+Cy^2+Dy+Exy+F).  My plan is to iterate through regions of data and perform a surface-fit, look at the error, see if it's a continuous surface (which would probably indicate a feature in the image).

I was previously able to find quadratic curves (f(x) = Ax^2+Bx+C) in the image data by sampling lines, by using the equations on this site

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128170354/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/72047.html)

this worked well, was  promising, but it would be much more useful for my task to find 2-D regions that form continuous surfaces.

I see lots of articles indicating that least squares regressions scales up to multiple dimensions, but I'm not able to find code for this  Hopefully there is a "closed form" (non-iterative, just compute from your data points) solution, like described above for 1D data.  Does anybody know of some source or pseudocode that accomplishes this?  Thanks.

(Sorry if my terminology is a bit off.)

Comment: You write `f(x,y) = Ax^2+Bx+Cy^2+D+E` but do you mean `f(x,y) = Ax+Bx^2+Cy+Dy^2+Exy+F`?

Comment: Oops, yes thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your background is, but if you know some linear algebra you will find [linear least squares on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#The_general_problem) useful.

Lets take the following example. Say we have the following image

[image]

and we want to know how well this fits to a 2D quadratic function in a least squares sense.

Probably the most straightforward way to solve the problem is to compute the optimal coefficients in a least squares sense, then check the error.

First we need to describe the matrices.

Let `X` be a matrix containing every x,y coordinate in the image, taking the form

```
X = [x1  x1^2  y1  y1^2  x1*y1  1;
     x2  x2^2  y2  y2^2  x2*y2  1;
     ...
     xN  xN^2  yN  yN^2  xN*yN  1];
```

For the example image above, X would be a `100x6` matrix.

Let `y` be the image intensity values in a vector of the form

```
y = [img(x1,y1);
     img(x2,y2);
     ...
     img(xN,yN)]
```

In this case `y` is a 100 element column vector.

We want to minimize the least squares objective function `S` with respect to the vector of coefficients `b`

```
S(b) = |y - X*b|^2
```

where `|.|` is the L2 norm and `b` is the desired coefficients

```
b = [A;
     B;
     C;
     D;
     E;
     F]
```

Taking the vector derivative of `S(b)` with respect to `b`, setting to zero, and solving for `b` [leads to the standard least squares solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Derivation_directly_in_terms_of_matrices).

```
b = inv(X'X)*X'*y
```

where `inv` is the matrix inverse, `'` is transpose, and `*` is matrix multiplication.

MATLAB example.

```
% Generate an image

% define x,y coordinates for each location in the image
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:10,1:10);

% true coefficients
b_true = [0.1 0.5 0.3 -0.4 0.4 124];
% magnitude of noise
P = 2;
% create image
img = b_true(1).*x + b_true(2).*x.^2 + b_true(3).*y + b_true(4).*y.^2 + b_true(5).*x.*y + b_true(6);
noise = P*randn(10,10);
img = img + noise;

% Begin least squares optimization

% create matrices
X = [x(:) x(:).^2 y(:) y(:).^2 x(:).*y(:) ones(size(x(:)))];
y = img(:);

% estimated coefficients
b = (X.'*X)\(X.')*y

% mean square error (expected to be near P^2)
E = 1/numel(y) * sum((y - X*b).^2)
```

Output

```
b =

    0.0906
    0.5093
    0.1245
   -0.3733
    0.3776
  124.5412


E =

    3.4699
```

In your application you would probably want to define some threshold such that when `E < threshold` you accept the image (or image region) as a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Oh my gosh... how did I not see this??   Thanks so much for the thorough answer!  Digesting it now...